# Understanding Hibernate Version History and Compatibility of its modules with each Other

Tags: java, hibernate, versioning

Is there any good link or documentation regarding Hibernate Version History.
My Confusion starts at Hibernate 3.3 when [modularisation](http://in.relation.to/9384.lace) was introduced.

For e.g if i want to use hibernate-validator 3.x  with hibernate 3.2.6ga (before 3.3 its was single jar) would it be compatible?

I want to know compatibility between different modules and also their compatibility with Single Hibernate Jars Releases (like **3.2.6ga** )
By compatibility i mean what's the minimum required version.

I am hibernate newbie.so completely lost in Hibernate Version Jungle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Hibernate Compatibility Matrix maintained by Hibernate community. It shows exactly which version of Hibernate component is compatible with others.

[Hibenate Compatibility Matrix](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCompatibilityMatrix)

So as per the matrix, Hibernate-validator-3.x is compatible with hibernate-3.2.6ga.

Comment: +1 for you but As per the Link, pre 3.3 Hibernate Jars like 3.2.6ga is mentioned as hibernate-core module,so can we assume that single jars were renamed as hibernate-core module (essentially its a core feature)  and additional features were added as seperate module